# How can I mock and know if the method of a parent class has been called?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

I want to test the next class:

```
class B extends A {
  getOptions(params) {
     const options = super.getOptions(params);
     return {...options, newProperty: "newProperty"}
  }
}
```

For example for this case:

```
const instanceB= new B();
instanceB.getOptions({})
```

How can I know if `super.getOptions(params)` have been called and how can I modified  it behavior with a mock using Jest?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure you can.  Doing similar things, I use composition, over inheritance, so I would inject some functionality from A using standard Dependency Injection (DI) which can then be easily mock'd for testing.

Comment: I agree, for testing is better DI. Unfortunately, I can not change inheritance ( legacy code ). Thanks @StevenScott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const A = require("./A");
const B = require("./B");

describe("...", () => {
    it("...", async () => {
        const instanceB = new B();

        const getOptionsSpy = jest
            .spyOn(A.prototype, "getOptions")
            .mockResolvedValue({ foo: 1 });

        const result = await instanceB.getOptions({ bar: 2 });

        expect(getOptionsSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(result).toEqual({ foo: 1, bar: 2 });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @StevenScott I could figure out this solution.